# How to read multiple barcodes with Google Code scanner beta

Tags: barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I have an use case where there will be multiple barcodes. I have to read the first one. I have built the app using [Google code scanner Beta](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/code-scanner) with GmsBarcodeScanner. But when I scan it always reads the smallest barcode and returns back to the app. Is there a way to filter out from the scanner itself to read based on barcode length or starting with string?